# How do I know what brake rotors to get for my bike?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, cyclocross, road, rotor

In the next month or so I plan on getting the 2019 Trek Crockett 5 as a cyclocross/road bike. I will also be getting some nicer road wheels for the bike so I can swap out the wheels whenever needed. Of course I plan on getting the same cassette for the rear wheel, but I was wondering about the brake rotors. On Trek's site it says the brakeset is "TRP Spyre mechanical disc" and in the close up of the brake rotors it says "160-35" on the rotor. I'm assuming this means they are 160mm rotors, but I don't know if I need to get the exact same discs that come with the bike or if I can just get any 160mm rotors.

Here's the link to the bike for more info: https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/road-bikes/cyclocross-bikes/crockett/crockett-5-disc/p/23092/?colorCode=black

Thanks!

Comment: The question can be edited anytime if you have something to add, like make it more specific.

Answer (score 7):

TR160-35 is the model number. They are 160mm Centerlock rotors. If your new wheels have Centerlock hubs, then you need either centerlock rotors or adaptors. If the wheels are 6-bolt, then you need 6-bolt rotors. Either way you'll want 160mm rotors and to keep it easy, I'd stick with Tektro rotors for this system.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for a very detailed answer!

Comment: Don’t see the reason for sticking to tektro rotors but agree otherwise

Answer (score 4):

[There are two rotor interface types](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56879/6-bolt-vs-centre-lock-pros-and-cons), you need to get something that matches hubs on the new wheelset. As you already noted, rotor diameter should be the same. The rotors should not necessarily be the same, but hub distance and rotor thickness tolerances *might* (or not) cause brake rub after swapping wheels, but that can be adressed by caliper position (adjusted so no rub happens with both wheelsets) or shims between rotor and hub.

Comment: Unless one can shim both rotors to be at exactly the same distance from the left drop out it is necessary to adjust the calipers with every week swap. @Nate consider if that interferes with your intented use of an extra wheel set.

Answer (score 4):

In addition some rotors claim not to be suitable for metal pads, but all seem to be suitable for organic pads. This is only an issue if you run metal pads.