# Mechanical disc rotor for CUBE MTB - front wheel : Shimano 559x17-21c

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, disc-brake, mechanical

Seeking advice with regards to the size of disc brakes for front wheel.

Cube mountain bike. Front wheel: Shimano 559x17-21c. Disc brake: Shimano brake disc sm-rt 10 Centre Lock 160mm

[image: The image is of Shimano mechanical brake disc sm-rt 10 Centre Lock 160mm]

Could you kindly advise - would a 160mm brake disc be suitable for a cube MTB - front wheel size- 559x17-21c I do not have a picture of the bike at present, if necessary I could get it and send it later.  Not sure of the model either.

Many Thanks,

Tam

Comment: I'm not an MTBer but 160 sounds small for the front. Do you not have an existing rotor to measure?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus is perfectly fine for XC use, but that of course also depends on rider weight or trail conditions too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know what brake rotors to get for my bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58770/how-do-i-know-what-brake-rotors-to-get-for-my-bike)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question - you seem to say that you currently have a (factory-installed) sm-rt 10 160mm rotor, and ask whether a 160mm rotor would be suitable? If so: probably yes - the vendor likely wouldn't install it otherwise ;-)

Comment: Like anderas, I don't think I understand the question.  Can you try to add a little more detail?

Comment: What size brake rotor to get for a MTB - front wheel - 559x17 - 21c?

Comment: Rotor size is not wholly determined by the wheel size, riding style and rider weight are bigger factors.

Comment: Rotor size is also determined by where the caliper is, and how far it can be moved.  You may need to buy/fit an adapter to change to a different rotor size from stock.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, your bike already uses 160 mm Centerlock disc at front. If you need a new disc instead of worn/damaged old one, *any* 160 mm Centerlock disc will be compatible.

There are some concerns about certain brake pads types not being compatible with all disc types, but in my opinion it does not matter, all pads just work with metal discs.

Do not go with different diameter of discs unless you experience lack of stopping power. If so, bigger 180 mm discs may be an answer, but you'll need to check if they are compatible with your fork and won't break bicycle warranty. Besides, an extra/different adapter is usually needed to install a disc of a different size.