# How to chose the correct hydraulic disc brake rotor size for touring bike?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, rotor

I have ordered a Shimano Deore M6000 disc brake set. What rotor size should I chose for my touring bike?
I am 85 kg and my bike is approximately 15-20 kg.

Comment: I assume you are building a bike up from a frame so do not have an existing disc.  What mass of luggage are you planning to put on the bike?

Comment: Maximum 5-10 kg.
I have a working bike, but I am gonna remove my V-brake and use disc brake instead.

Comment: You said your bike originally had V-brakes (i.e., rim brakes), does the frame have mounts for disc brakes?  It is fairly rare for frames to have mountings for both disc and rim brakes

Comment: as a point of reference, my tourer was sold with 160mm rotors for its *cable* discs and fitted with sintered pads as stock.  Stopping power is excellent (unless they get oily muck on them but that's another story) and wear is good.  At the bottom of a long descent stuck behind cars they can get really rather hot (sizzling if splashed with water, my plans to measure the temperature so far haven't been done)

Comment: Related  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58770/how-do-i-know-what-brake-rotors-to-get-for-my-bike      possibly a dupe if you squint.

Answer (score 3):

There's no one right answer.

Most get by with 160 front and rear. There can be some virtue in going to 180, especially in front, to help manage heat and ensure a good power level when descending mountains heavily loaded, if that's going to be a thing you do much. Not every frame/fork is strong enough or has clearance for 180, however. The forks on more MTB-ish/adventure/bikepacking type bikes will often be able to handle it, while more road type forks may chatter and flex too much.

Running 140 either front or back, as often see on road or cross bikes, would generally be not adequate for loaded use.

Comment: I've tried to use 180 rotor on my XC30 fork, but noticed massive vibration when braking (so yes, the fork is not string enough), so switched back to 160